# Retrieve tree data from Mongoose in recursive node function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, tree

I am trying to retrieve data in a tree format from Mongodb recursively using Mongoose in a Node Express app. I'm trying to do it with promises and I am clearly not doing it right.

Say you have the mongodb table `foos`':

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b5fb27232db7b13a1090577"
    },
    "bazs": [
        {
            "$oid": "5b626a2e325c181bdf4fba08"
        }
    ],
    "bars": [
        {
            "$oid": "5b5fb3cc32db7b13a1090579"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Parent1",
    "accountId": "5b5fb27132db7b13a1090576",
    "__v": 0
}
```

So this has two different kind of child objects. Also, the `baz` objects have other `baz` objects as children, as well as `bar` objects. Say this is the table that the id for `bars`:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b626a2e325c181bdf4fba08"
    },
    "bazs": [
        {
            "$oid": "5b5fb3cc32db7b75fa01"
        }
    ],
    "bars": [
        {
            "$oid": "5b5fb3c7cdaf740a500a"
        }
    ],
    "accountId": "5b5fb27132db7b13a1090576",
    "parent": {
        "$oid": "5b5fb27232db7b13a1090577"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I've been using a recursive function in a thunk waiting for an object type to retrieve using Mongoose.

```
const getObjectRecursive = (type, id)=>{     //'type' will be 'Foo' or 'Bar'
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        type.findOne.call(type, {_id:id},{}, err=>{
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
        })
            .then((rslt)=>{
                const result = rslt;
                const bars = result.bars;
                const bazs = result.bazs;
                result.children = {};
                result.children.bars = tasks.map(async barId=>{
                    const barIdString = barId.toString();
                    await getBarRecursive(barIdString, err=>{
                        if(err){
                            reject(err);
                        }
                    });
                });
                result.children.bazs = bazs.map(async eventId=>{
                    const bazIdString = bazId.toString();
                    await Baz.findOne({_id:eventIdString}, {},err=>{
                        if(err){
                            reject(err);
                        }
                    });
                });
                resolve(result);
            })
    });

}
```

And I use it in these two functions:

```
const getBarRecursive = (taskId)=>{
    return getObjectRecursive(Bar, taskId);

}

const getFooRecursive=(categoryId)=>{
    return getObjectRecursive(Foo,categoryId);
};
```

Which are called by this route:

```
router.get('/:id', verifyToken, (req,res)=>{
    Branch.getFooRecursive(req.params.id)
        .then(
            (foo)=>{
                res.status(200).send(cat);
            },
            (err)=>{
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
        )
});
```

This is meant to return the tree object recursively and all the objects' children. What's happening is that the children objects `result.children.bars` and `result.children.bazs` become promises that never get fulfilled.

This is not the best way to do this, I know. I'm clearly not doing promises right. I also thought about retrieving the table using a $graphLookup, but I can't figure out how to do that since the children come from different collections.

How can I make the app retrieve the children to any depth?

UPDATE: This is still not working. I've changed the recursive function to this:

```
const getObjectRecursive = async (type, id)=>{     
    const rslt = await type.findOne.call(type, {_id:id},{}, {}, err=>{
        if(err){
            return({err: err});
        }
    });

    const result = rslt.toObject();
    const bars = result.bars;
    const bazs = result.bazs;
    result.children = {};
    result.children.bars = tasks.map(async barId=>{
        const barIdString = barId.toString();
        await getBarRecursive(barIdString, err=>{
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
    result.children.bazs = bazs.map(async eventId=>{
        const bazIdString = bazId.toString();
        await Baz.findOne({_id:eventIdString}, {},err=>{
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
    return result
};
```

Everything else is the same. What's happening now is that the promises containing the `bar` result isn't being fulfilled until AFTER the result is sent to the client, so I am getting an empty object in it's place, like this:

```
{
    "bars": [
        "5b626a2e325c181bdf4fba08"
    ],
    "bazs": [],
    "_id": "5b5fb27232db7b13a1090577",
    "__v": 0,
    "children": {
        "bars": [
            {}
        ],
        "bazs": []
    }
}
```

Some things I've tried:

- placing the `bars.map(async barId=>...` etc. inside a Promises.all statement and assigning it to `result.children` in a `.then(...)` statement
- placing the `bars.map(async barId=>...` etc. inside a separate async function and then saying `result.children.bars = await getAllTasks(tasks)`

How can I make sure my promise is fulfilled before the result is sent?

Comment: The example heavily uses https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it . Mongoose supports promises. Why do you keep using findOne callback? And you're mixing these things with async/await. The problem would likely be solved if you were using async/await everywhere.

Comment: So you're saying instead of making findObjectRecursive return a promise, make it and getFooRecursive and getBarRecursive into async functions?

Comment: You still can use recursion if you need but with much cleaner control flow that leaves less space for error. `const result = await type.findOne(...)`, etc.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow

Comment: So this has succeeded in getting my promises fulfilled, thank you. It looks like I have another problem where the stuff I'm adding to my returned objects isn't being included in what's returned but that's something else. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone who's wondering, the problem was that I was trying to add properties onto a Mongoose object, so they weren't being returned. I changed the line `const result = rslt` to `const result = rslt.toObject()` which turned it into a plain (non-mongoose) object so I could add things to it.

Comment: Btw, it's a good idea to do this by default, unless you need the opposite. This is done like `const result = await type.findOne(...).lean()`.

Comment: So it's still not quite working because some of my promises aren't being fulfilled until after the result is sent. The problem's described in the update above.

Comment: There are numerous problems here. I tried to explain them. I cannot guarantee that this will work because the logic depends on actual data structure. Since there's a bunch of requests and nested promises, it may be better to move some of these requests to Mongo side or restructure data. The abundance of `findOne` is a clue that there could be a single `find` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose supports promises for a long time, there is no need to use callbacks. `reject` function is undefined, its use will result in exception. Also, `call` is unjustified here.  There are also several inconsistencies, `tasks` vs `bars` and `eventId` vs `bazId`. All of them will prevent the code from working normally

It should be something like:

```
const getObjectRecursive = async (type, id)=>{     
    const result = await type.findOne({_id:id}).lean();
    const barsPromises = result.bars.map(barId=>{
        return getBarRecursive(barId.toString()); // shouldn't it accept 2 args?
    });
    const bazsPromises = result.bazs.map(bazId =>{
        return Baz.findOne({_id:bazId.toString()}).lean();
    });

    const [bars, bazs] = await Promise.all([
      Promise.all(barsPromises),
      Promise.all(bazsPromises)
    ]);
    result.children = { bars, bazs };

    return result;
};
```